# Query optimization with joins and unions and fulltext boolean search

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have the following base tables with subtables for searchbait.  (This is on aws aurora with mysql 5.7 compatibility)

```
tblA (id, userId, title, ...)
tblB (id, userId, title, ...)

tblA_searchBait (id->tblA.id, keywords)
tblB_searchBait (id->tblB.id, keywords)
```

I need to do a boolean fulltext search to obtain combined results in a single query.  Currently I use the following:

```
select          base.title as title,
                match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode) as relevance
from            tblA as base
                join tblA_searchBait as search on search.id = base.id           
where           base.userId = ? and 
                match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode)

union all

select          base.title as title,
                match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode) as relevance 
from            tblB as base
                join tblB_searchBait as search on search.id = base.id           
where           base.userId = ? and 
                match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode)

order by        relevance desc              
limit ?, ?;
```

This works, but I am wondering:  Are there ways the query can be made more performant?  (Please note, I cannot change the schema of the tables.). Specifically I'm wondering if there's any difference with something like this:

```
  select            base.title as title,
                    match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode) as relevance
    from            tblA as base
                    join tblA_searchBait as search on search.id = base.id   
                    and base.userId = ?     
    where           match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode)
    
    union all
    
    select          base.title as title,
                    match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode) as relevance 
    from            tblB as base
                    join tblB_searchBait as search on search.id = base.id 
                    and base.userId = ?         
    where           match(search.keywords) against (? in boolean mode)
    
    order by        relevance desc              
    limit ?, ?;
```

Comment: please read uo on https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions/3035#3035 and add more information

Comment: Please point out the difference between the two queries; they seem to be the same.

Comment: @rick -- in the first query the where clause specifies the userId -- in the second query the inner join specifies the userId -- I am not sure if this makes any practical difference, but I have wondered

Comment: @user1031947 - Now I see.  I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not trust the "relevance" provided by two different tables to be comparable.  So, I would work on putting all the Fulltext data into a single table.

Why have 2 similar subtables?

If you had a column in your super-table (if you have such?), then the relative relevance would be possible *and* the query would run about twice as fast.

> I cannot change the schema of the tables.

Sorry. but changing the schema is often a step in optimization.

**WHERE vs ON**

"Proper" coding specifies the relationship between JOINed tables in the `ON` clause and filtering in the `WHERE` clause.  I don't know of a case in `JOIN` where it matters which place things are put.  (It matters for `LEFT JOIN`.)

You can check that they are identical by doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` for each version.  The Warning should be the `SELECT` spelled out as the Optimizer sees it.  That will include, among other things, moving `ON` clauses into `WHERE` (for whatever reason).

**UNION and parens**

The final `ORDER BY` is right next to a `SELECT`.  Or is it right next to a `UNION`?  I like to make it unambiguous by doing this:

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION 
( SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

Note that each `SELECT` could also have its own `ORDER BY`, hence there could be a total of 3 `ORDER BYs`.  (There are obscure cases where such is valid.)